# How to get Median of column x within each percentile in sql?

Tags: sql, median, netezza, percentile-cont

Is there a code in sql that will allow me to get a median of column x within each percentile I pulled in one select statement?  Here is the percentiles I pulled.  I am trying to avoid coding the median individually and merge them together.  Thanks!

```
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.01) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PP01DS  ASC) as percentile_01,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.05) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PP01DS  ASC) as percentile_05,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.10) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PP01DS  ASC) as percentile_10,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.20) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PP01DS  ASC) as percentile_20,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.30) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PP01DS  ASC) as percentile_30,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.40) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PP01DS  ASC) as percentile_40,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PP01DS  ASC) as percentile_50,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.60) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PP01DS  ASC) as percentile_60,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.70) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PP01DS  ASC) as percentile_70,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.80) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PP01DS  ASC) as percentile_80,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.90) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PP01DS  ASC) as percentile_90,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.99) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PP01DS  ASC) as percentile_99,
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Medians are the "mid point" of any sample, so you need access to all the rows of each percentile group. Hence you do NOT want to pivot the data into 12 percentile columns then attempt to calculate medians for each of those.  Use an intermediate result that is not pivoted (maybe in a CTE)  then calculate medians, then pivot the result.

Comment: Here is the sample data and expected results: 
PP01DS PLANPAY01DS
1 23.93533333
1.07142857 25.015
1.07142857 26.31
1.07142857 26.45928571
1.07142857 26.47321429
1.16666667 24.082
1.42857143 25.20607143
1.42857143 25.44928571
2 23.48033333
5.17266667 20.69
5.32714286 21.30785714
5.34285714 21.37142857
8.16142857 19.04357143
 
 
PERCENTILE_50 of PP01DS = 1.428571
Median PlanPay01DS = 25.32768
 
PERCENTILE_80 of PP01DS = 5.265352
Median PlanPay01DS =  25.11053

Comment: Here is the simpler example 
PP01DS PLANPAY01DS
1 10
2 20
3 30
5 50
 
 
PERCENTILE_50 of PP01DS =  2.5
Median PlanPay01DS =  15